# Using Scikit-learn Pipeline vs list append in python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I want to do text data pre-processing using my own function and then applying a countvectorizer. Can I use a pipeline for these two works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Scikit-learn has the CountVectorizer class which is a transformer, and you can create the text data pre-processing transformer following the [scikit-learn API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html).

[This beautiful blog](https://dreisbach.us/articles/building-scikit-learn-compatible-transformers/) shows you how to build a custom transformer and how to use it in a pipeline, follow it.